# <> syntax in Typescript Angular2

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm new to Angular2 and I don't understand that <> syntax :

example 1 ( from https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/dependency-injection.html ) :

```
let mockService = <HeroService> {getHeroes: () => expectedHeroes }
```

example 2 ( from https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html )

```
deleteRequest = new EventEmitter<Hero>();
```

Any help or reference to a comprehensive answer is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<HeroService> {getHeroes: () => expectedHeroes }` corresponds to a cast / type assertion to the `HeroService` class. The returned object will follow the structure of this class.

`new EventEmitter<Hero>();` is a way to parametrize the `EventEmitter` class (generics) to tell that it'll handle elements of type `Hero`. In the case of the `EventEmitter` class (see https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/%40angular/facade/src/async.ts#L80), it ensures that objects used as a parameter of the `emit` method must be of type `Hero`.

See the following links for more details:

- https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/type-assertion.html
- https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html

Comment: thanks, is there any more uses of that <> syntax ? Do you have a link to a comprehensive <> syntax use ? I'm surprised i didn't find any.

Comment: I'd recommend https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/type-assertion.html and https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html

Answer (score 2):

They're called "type assertions" and documented in the [TypeScript manual](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md#416-type-assertions).

By the way, it's probably best not to call them "casts". It is "asserting" to the compiler that a value should be thought of as a particular type. It will remain unhappy if you tell it to think of something as a type it can't possibly be. In the other words, the asserted type must be **narrower**. Note also the alternative syntax `as Type` following the value, which is more readable and avoids conflicts with React.